# Redirect 301 from http to https doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've this .htaccess in my share web hosting.

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]


RedirectMatch 301 ^/directory(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/directory/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/directory\-2014\.03\.04(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/directory\-2014\.03\.04/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

I want all calls to http://www.example.com or http://example.com that redirect to https://www.example.com. But with my setup does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

The above will first change `http://domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com` then it will redirect `http://www.domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com` if it isn't `https://`

Comment: Hi!!!Thanks for your answer, but ... It doesn't works to me. I don't understand anything because there is no any redirection when I write domain.com or www.domain.com or the same with http:// before of them